# Looping over local variables

Tags: rust

In Rust, is there a cleaner way for me to write this?

```rust
for i in [&mut foo, &mut bar, &mut baz, &mut quux, &mut bob].iter_mut() {
    i.handle_event(event)
}
```

The above loop appears in three places in my function. `foo`, `bar` etc are mutable local variables all of the same type.

```rust
let mut foo = MyType::new(...);
let mut bar = MyType::new(...);
...
```

I don't want to write `let mut v = vec![foo, bar, baz, quuz, bob]` because the vector would consume the variables. I also need to write things like `bar.set_strength(10)` or whatever, and I don't want to write `v[1].set_strength(10)`; the code is much clearer if I can refer to each by name.

Comment: This is probably the best you can do based on the information you must convey to the compiler and the situation you're in. If you have this issue in multiple places, then you could write a macro to make it shorter, but it might not be clearer. Also, what's clean or not is somewhat subjective, so you might not get an answer you like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is any cleaner but here is one way to do this with a macro:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9463d4723eb3868759d9bfa856726d54)

```rust
macro_rules! mut_loop {
    ($i:pat in [$($var:ident),*] $block:block) => {
        for _mut_loop_var in [$(&mut $var),*].iter_mut() {
            let $i = &mut **_mut_loop_var;
            $block;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = 0u32;
    let mut bar = 0;
    let mut baz = 0;
    let mut quux = 0;
    let mut bob = 0;
    mut_loop!(i in [foo, bar, baz, quux, bob] {
        *i += 5;
        // i.handle_event(event)
    });
}
```